# I can't open X-UI panel address installed on my oracle ubuntu server

Tags: linux, nginx, vpn, ipv6

I have installed [x-ui](https://github.com/iprodev/x-ui) panel and it shows it's up and running on my server, but when I try to access my `server_ip:specified_port_for_x-ui` it says connection time out or the site can't be reached.

I searched through the internet and there was only one answer about this question suggesting forward ipv4 trafic to ipv6. But my server doesn't have ipv6, because if I available that, it gets into trouuble connecting to github!
I am also not sure if the problem has anything to do with the ipv6?

PS: I use oracle instance.

`sudo ufw allow specified_port` also didn't help.

Maybe I should install Nginx?

Comment: the software had 2 years ago the last update. if its not working I would suggest that you take a error notice on the github page. As a reminder home and end-user computing questions have to be asked on Super User